# Closing HTML Tags Before Opening New One in PHP

Tags: php, html, tidy

I have a couple thousand html chunks I'm looking to bulk edit with php.

The HTML format they are in that is complicating things is like this:

```
<table>
<table>
</table>
```

[PHP Tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) seems like a great solution.

I'm trying stuff like

```
$tidy = new Tidy();
$tidy_config = array( 
                 'clean' => true, 
                 'output-html' => true, 
                 'show-body-only' => true, 
                 'wrap' => 0, 
                 'drop-proprietary-attributes' => true,
                 'repeated-attributes' => 'keep-first'
                 ); 

$tidy = tidy_parse_string($htmlstring, $tidy_config, 'UTF8'); 
$tidy->cleanRepair(); 
echo $tidy;
```

I also came across this function

```
function closetags($html) {
    preg_match_all('#<([a-z]+)(?: .*)?(?<![/|/ ])>#iU', $html, $result);
    $openedtags = $result[1];
    preg_match_all('#</([a-z]+)>#iU', $html, $result);
    $closedtags = $result[1];
    $len_opened = count($openedtags);
if (count($closedtags) == $len_opened) {
    return $html;
}
    $openedtags = array_reverse($openedtags);

for ($i=0; $i < $len_opened; $i++) {
    if (!in_array($openedtags[$i], $closedtags)) {
        $html .= '</'.$openedtags[$i].'>';
    } else {
        unset($closedtags[array_search($openedtags[$i], $closedtags)]);
    }
}
    return $html;
}
```

Both are basically returning the same thing with these HTML blocks

```
<table>
<table>
</table>
</table>
```

So they are closing it, but.. the weird way in which these blocks of html are formatted, overlapping the tables like this output is causing some major issues.

I need to close the tags BEFORE opening a new one.. meaning an output like this:

```
<table>
</table>
<table>
</table>
```

I'm currently searching through the [Tidy Quick Reference](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html) manual to see if there's an option for me, but I haven't found anything yet.

edit: went through the whole reference page.. tried many things, nothing worked. Don't think it's something I can do in Tidy (correct me if I'm wrong..)

Anyone have any ideas with this?

Comment: PHP Tidy is doing the same thing that a browser does when it gets invalid HTML like this. It assumes that repeated start tags are nested, not sequential.

Comment: @bbruman, you question will be largely improved if you can provide some input samples and the expected output.  I don't/haven't used Tidy, so I may or may not be able to assist you.  Either way, improving your question will give you a better chance of receiving a quality answer before your question "ages away".

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's been a couple weeks since I first started this project and as of now moved onto a better strategy to bulk edit these via completely removing the HTML tags, encompassing the content lines into variables and constructing my own HTML template with codeigniter.  So me personally, don't really need a solution any more. I do think it's an interesting question though and got me thinking about the nuances of valid and invalid HTML.  I'd be interested solely for educational purposes if someone has a solution, but not worried about it "aging away"